# Remove white bar under a div

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```html
<div class="image-overlay" style="margin:0">
  <img src="images/AboutMeBG.png" alt="About Me Image" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="image-overlay-text">
    <h2 class="stroke-text">My Projects</h2>
    <p class="stroke-text"><em>More Coming Soon...</em></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

That has an annoying little bar under it, I am not entirely sure how to remove it, nothing I have tried has worked so far.

[Here is an image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5ovP.png)

I tried editing the styles.css, I tried adding a margin, I was expeting this to be an easy fix but I am not sure ‍♂️

Comment: Share your CSS code.

Comment: @JoydipPaul Here is the CSS Code, https://00.yt/1d It was too long to fit in here xD

Comment: The bar line did not come from your code. It is the image issue. Use another banner image.

Comment: @JoydipPaul The thing is, if I use another image it sill has the bar, so I might just have to try and not use images :/